# How one can cast ref to enum value as u16 (base enum type) in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums, reference, clone, primitive-types

Given:

```rust
#[repr(u16)]
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Eq, Hash, Clone)]
pub enum SomeEnum {
    SomeValue1 = 1,
    SomeValue2 = 1 << 2 | Self::SomeValue1 as u16, // some bitmasks
    // ...
}

pub fn some_check(actual_value_ref: &SomeEnum, base_value: SomeEnum) -> bool {
    let actual_value_u16 = actual_value_ref.clone() as u16; // how to cast without cloning?
    let base_value_u16 = base_value as u16;
    actual_value_u16 & base_value_u16 == base_value_u16 // bitmask operation
}
```

How one can get value by reference **for a primitive** without explicit cloning?
Cloning of `u16` does not look like a tragedy but what's the right way to do it?
Since enum is explicitly marked as `#[repr(u16)]` why compiler doesn't do it out-of-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid explicit `clone`ing, I think it should suffice to `derive(Copy)` for `SomeEnum`.

Comment: it already has it (`#[derive(.., Clone)]`). It can be solved with deriving of `Copy` and `*actual_filter_type as u16` but this is what i'd like to avoid - having a copy which seems to be unneeded overhead.

Comment: @4ntoine You should use `Copy`, it doesn't add any overhead. If you're making a `u16`, the only way to avoid "copying" bytes to make it would be via a reference, which would actually be more work. See this example on [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Tzs4r3), its literally one instruction.

Comment: @4ntoine I thought of `Copy` - updated my answer.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken `copy` is bitwise-copy. So if for instance i have 5 checks (`some_check` calls) it will be copied 5 times. Even though it's fast it sounds very strange to have this overhead if having a reference (borrowed) to the original value. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You do realise that a reference is Copy, and 4 times the size of a u16, and requires an indirection every time you need to work with the actual u16 behind it?

Comment: @Masklinn makes sense